# CEFSharp modifies or truncates geocode address data from Google Maps v3 api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, lang, cefsharp

To reproduce, download CefSharp from here:
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

And run the CefSharp.WinForms.Example

Now run my fiddle on your browser and the CefSharp browser:
http://jsfiddle.net/bjmL9/

I added an alert displaying full address data on click (street_number, route, neighborhood, locality, administrative_area_level_2, administrative_area_level_1, country, postal_code).

Compare the data displayed on your browser to the one on the CefSharp browser.

The problem:
In my browser, the locality shows as "Culiacán Rosales", but on the Cef browser it gets truncated to "Culiacán". The country behaves weird too with Cef displaying "Mexico" instead of "México" (unaccented).

I am on the edge of quitting cef cuz i can't get a google match on this problem and no idea how to fix it...

This is the code of the fiddle since it won't last for ever:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <link href="MapStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      var geocoder;

      function initialize() {
          var placeMarkers = [];
          geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var aquamiller = new google.maps.LatLng(
              24.832956, 
              -107.389775);

          var mapOptions = {
              zoom: 16,
              center: aquamiller,
          };

          map = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById('map-canvas'), 
              mapOptions);

          createSearchBar(map, placeMarkers);

          google.maps.event.addListener(
              map,
              'click', 
              function(e) {
                  getAddress(e.latLng, function(address) {
                      alert(
                        address.street_number + ', ' +
                        address.route + ', ' +
                        address.neighborhood + ', ' +
                        address.locality + ', ' +
                        address.administrative_area_level_2 + ', ' +
                        address.administrative_area_level_1 + ', ' +
                        address.country + ', ' +
                        address.postal_code);
                  });
              });
      }

      function getAddress(latLng, callBack)
      {
          geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latLng}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if (results[0]) {
                var address = {};
                var components = results[0].address_components;
                for (var i = 0 ; i< components.length ; i++) {
                  address[components[i].types[0]] = components[i].long_name;
                }
                callBack(address);
              }
              else {
                alert('No results found');
              }
            }
            else {
              alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
            }
          });
      }

      function createSearchBar(map, markers)
      {
          var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('pac-input'));
          map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

          var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

          google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            console.log(places);
            for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
              marker.setMap(null);
            }

            markers = [];
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
              var image = {
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
              };

              // Create a marker for each place.
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: place.name,
                position: place.geometry.location
              });

              markers.push(marker);

              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
              console.log(place.geometry.location);
            }
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            map.setZoom(16);
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
          });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you isolate it to either CEF or CefSharp by using `cefclient.exe` from the CEF binary download? Which CefSharp version do you use?

Comment: I am using this this NuGet: http://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/
Mainly because i need the RegisterJsObject to interact with the Google map in winforms.

Comment: Where are those binaries and that cefclient.exe you want me to try out?
Is this repository:
https://github.com/cefsharp/cef-binary

Comment: You *could* use CefSharps `cefclient.exe` from our clone repo there yes. (Of course pick the the tag matching the CefSharp release you have) Or the already compiled (I think) from upstream CEF projects official binary releases at http://www.magpcss.net/cef_downloads/index.php?query=label%3A~Deprecated+label%3ACEF1+label%3Abinary#list

Comment: I just tried using `CefSharp.WinForms.Example.exe` from master head - which seems to work alright with the accented chars - and I didn't see any truncation. But if you **need** the `RegisterJSObject` I can of course understand why you picked the CefSharp1 NuGet (until it's available in master). As you probably know CEF1 has been retired upstream.

Comment: Ah - read your message again and tried once more. I just looked at the street names not the locality. So both errors are also there with CefSharp from master.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of CEF1 being retired, as soon as CEF3 gets the RegisterJSObject implementation, i am moving on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey wait once more I see the same behavior (missing " Rosales" and accent in "México") with both my standard Chrome 35 and IE 10.

So, maybe it's related to a missing CEF language pack: https://github.com/cefsharp/cef-binary/tree/cef_binary_1.1364.1123/Release/locales .. the NuGet you  use probably only has `en-US.pak`

... Tested a bit more with your fiddle example. Dropping es.pak in my install didn't help. BUT I see similar if I search for "Sønderborg, Denmark" in the search box in the map. (At some locations there it says "S**o**nderborg", no "ø" ) So are you sure its browser related and not just the  google API?

**update** Asking with `language=es` as in:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=es&libraries=places"></script>
```

Alters the response from googles API. Currently verified using my iPad and your fiddle!

Comment: I tried chrome version 35.0.1916.153 m, Spanish locale, locality and country is fine.
Tried Firefox 30.0 Spanish locale, locality and country are fine too.
Tried IE 10.0.9200.16897, Spanish locale, shows up fine too.
And you are right about my locale, i got bin\Debug\locales\en-US.pak, should i remove it  and place a Spanish locale there?, does cef automatically picks this up?

Comment: I just tried placing the es.pak but with no luck =/

Comment: It might need a [lang](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=11670&p=21027&hilit=Language#p21027) setting. Try isolating with `cefclient.exe`. Also the CEF forum might have deeper knowledge.

Comment: It's strange I can't replicate your successes with stock Chrome/IE (I don't have Spanish in my languages for them). How do yours behave if you remove Spanish?

Comment: Yes, address data gets truncated as soon as i change the language to english. Tested on Firefox and Chrome. Now, shouldn't cef work normally too by changing the locale to Spanish?
How can i change it?

Comment: Give it the `lang` as mentioned above - linked to CEF forum :-)